# Subtracting rows depending on values of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables purchase, I want to subtract purchase date. depending on Customer ID, there are repeating customer ID's, so I want to subtract purchase date of Customer ID 105 and 105, 108 and 108 etc.

[image]

I have the following code, but it is subtracting each purchase date from the next purchase date

```
     SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,P1.PURCHASEDATE,P2.PURCHASEDATE) AS "diff in days since last purchase"
    FROM Purchases P1
    JOIN Purchases P2
    ON P1.CustomerID= P2.CustomerID
```

Comment: So your result shall only contain customers with at least two entries in the table. Yes? And in case there are several entries for one customer, you want to see the difference between first purchase and last one? Or between last one and second last one? Or what else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding to your `ON` a not equal: `P1.PURCHASEID <> P2.PURCHASEID` , meaning something like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,P1.PURCHASEDATE,P2.PURCHASEDATE) AS "diff in days"
FROM Purchases P1
JOIN Purchases P2
(ON P1.CustomerID= P2.CustomerID and P1.PURCHASEID <> P2.PURCHASEID  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OUTER APPLY:

```
;WITH Purchases AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1,'2012-08-15',1,105,'a510'),
(2,'2012-08-15',2,102,'a510'),
(3,'2012-08-15',3,103,'a506'),
(4,'2012-08-16',1,105,'a510'),
(5,'2012-08-17',5,106,'a507'),
(6,'2012-08-17',5,107,'a509'),
(7,'2012-08-18',4,108,'a502'),
(8,'2012-08-19',2,108,'a510'),
(9,'2012-08-19',3,109,'a502'),
(10,'2012-08-20',3,110,'a503')
) as t(PurchaseID,PurchaseDate,Qty,CustomerID,ProductID)
)

SELECT  p1.*,
        DATEDIFF(DAY,P2.PurchaseDate,P1.PurchaseDate) as ddiff
FROM Purchases p1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM Purchases
    WHERE p1.CustomerID = CustomerID
        AND PurchaseDate < p1.PurchaseDate
    ORDER BY PurchaseDate DESC
) p2
```

Will output:

```
PurchaseID  PurchaseDate    Qty CustomerID  ProductID   ddiff
1           2012-08-15      1   105         a510        NULL
2           2012-08-15      2   102         a510        NULL
3           2012-08-15      3   103         a506        NULL
4           2012-08-16      1   105         a510        1
5           2012-08-17      5   106         a507        NULL
6           2012-08-17      5   107         a509        NULL
7           2012-08-18      4   108         a502        NULL
8           2012-08-19      2   108         a510        1
9           2012-08-19      3   109         a502        NULL
10          2012-08-20      3   110         a503        NULL
```

Also you can use [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) (SQL Server 2012 and up):

```
SELECT  *,
        DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(PurchaseDate,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY PurchaseDate),PurchaseDate) as ddiff
FROM Purchases
```